# Выборка из многомерного массива

Tags: php

У меня меня массив вот такого вида:

```
Array (
    [response] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [uid] => 267521920
            [first_name] => Лєна
            [last_name] => Дехтяр
            [deactivated] => banned
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [uid] => 73943565
            [first_name] => Михаил
            [last_name] => Лятавский
            [verified] => 0
        )
    )
)
```

Как из этого масива выбрать тех, у которых `[verified] => 0` и занести их `uid` (напр. `73943565`) в переменную?

Comment: надо было в ваш первый [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/469933/5079) внести уточнения, а не создавать новый (кнопка "править" под вопросом)

Comment: по вопросу: `$userList = $YOUR_ARRAY['response']; $uid = null; foreach ($userList as $user) { if (0 == $user['verified']) { $uid = $user['uid']; break; } }`, как-то так

Comment: @ВОРОН Пробую использовать ваш код но в результате у меня он мне показывает 267521920  но у этого пользователя нет [verified] у него [deactivated] а нужно получить пользователя [verified] Яуже пол ночи ищу решение и ничего не получается, наоборот еще больше запутался

Comment: @ВОРОН убрал break работает как надо. Ничего не понял.

Comment: вы не правильно сделали. У вас массив плохо читаем, не заметил, что `verified` может отсутствовать, поэтому перед `0 == $user['verified']` сделать проверку на существование такого ключа, например, `if (array_key_exists('verified', $user) && 0 == $user['verified']) {...}`. А сейчас у вас в логах куча варнингов о том, что ключ отсутствует в массиве + выбирается не первый неверифицированный пользователь, а последний

Comment: @ВОРОН Спасибо Вам ОГРОМНОЕ, Вы меня очень виручили, удачи Вам во всем и харошого настроения, еще раз благодарю Вас за помощ.

Comment: Вы посмотрите на ответ @0xdeface, если его способ немного переделать (сделать `return array_key_exists('verified', $s) && 0 == $s['verified']`), то на выходе вы получите всех пользователей, у которых `verified` равно 0, а не только одного как в моем способе. А получить `uid` этих пользователей уже можно будет через `foreach`

Comment: @BOPOH Мне как раз и нужен только один )

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Видел Ваш второй вопрос. Обратите внимание: у меня поддерживаются и чтение в массив, и перезапись элемента с нулевой верификацией.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу array() и других функций - читайте [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array.php).

К Вашей задаче подходит функция `array_walk()`, которая перебирает элементы массива аналогично циклу `foreach`, но позволяет применить к ним пользовательскую функцию, в нашем случае - `get_verified()` или `check_verified()`.

Процедуры `get_verified()` и `check_verified()` работают независимо друг от друга, причём `get_verified()` формирует массив `uid` непроверенных элементов, а `check_verified()` записывает `uid` на место нулевого `"verified"`.

В описании пользовательской функции ставим амперсанды на изменяемые величины - чтобы в функцию передавалась не копия элемента, а ссылка на него.

```
$multi_arr = array ( "response" => array ( 
    "0" => array ( "uid" => 267521920, "first_name" => Лєна, "last_name" => Дехтяр, "deactivated" =>banned ), 
    "1" => array ( "uid" => 73943565, "first_name" => Михаил, "last_name" => Лятавский, "verified" => 0 ) ) 
) ;

function check_verified(&$item, $key) {
    if (array_key_exists("verified",$item) && $item["verified"]===0) { 
        $item["verified"]=$item["uid"];
    } 
}

function get_verified($item, $key) {
    global $not_verified;
    if (array_key_exists("verified",$item) && $item["verified"]===0) {
        array_push($not_verified, $item["uid"]);
    }
}

var_dump($multi_arr);

// Вывод массива uid элементов, для которых verified = 0
$not_verified = array();
array_walk($multi_arr["response"], 'get_verified');
var_dump($not_verified);

// Замена verified = 0 на verified = uid
array_walk($multi_arr["response"], 'check_verified');
var_dump($multi_arr);

// Вывод массива uid элементов, для которых verified = 0
$not_verified = array();
array_walk($multi_arr["response"], 'get_verified');
var_dump($not_verified);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  'response' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'uid' => int 267521920
          'first_name' => string 'Лєна' (length=8)
          'last_name' => string 'Дехтяр' (length=12)
          'deactivated' => string 'banned' (length=6)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'uid' => int 73943565
          'first_name' => string 'Михаил' (length=12)
          'last_name' => string 'Лятавский' (length=18)
          'verified' => int 0
array (size=1)
  0 => int 73943565
array (size=1)
  'response' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'uid' => int 267521920
          'first_name' => string 'Лєна' (length=8)
          'last_name' => string 'Дехтяр' (length=12)
          'deactivated' => string 'banned' (length=6)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'uid' => int 73943565
          'first_name' => string 'Михаил' (length=12)
          'last_name' => string 'Лятавский' (length=18)
          'verified' => int 73943565
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Comment: `if($key="verified" && $item===0) $item = 73943565;` :)

Comment: @Visman спасибо :)

Comment: Супер решение :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ['response' => [['uid' => 267521920, 'first_name' => 'Лєна', 'last_name' => 'Дехтяр'],
               ['uid' => 73943565, 'first_name' => 'Михаил', 'verified' => 0 ]]];

if (array_key_exists('response', $arr))
    print_r(array_filter($arr['response'], function($s=0){ return array_key_exists('verified', $s);}));

//OUT:
//    Array
//    (
//        [1] => Array
//        (
//            [uid] => 73943565
//                [first_name] => Михаил
//                [verified] => 0
//            )
//    
//    )
```

Comment: пропущено $s=0.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно пробежаться по всем юзерам, проверяя, есть ли поле `verified` и равно ли оно `0`. Если есть и равно, то записать `uid` в массив результатов:

```
$vkData = ['response' => [
    ['uid' => 267521920, 'first_name' => 'Лєна',   'last_name' => 'Дехтяр',    'deactivated' => 'banned' ],
    ['uid' => 73943565,  'first_name' => 'Михаил', 'last_name' => 'Лятавский', 'verified' => 0 ]
  ]
]; 

$notVerified = [];
if( isset($vkData['response'])) {
    foreach( $vkData['response'] AS $user) {
        if( isset( $user['verified'])  &&  $user['verified'] == 0) $notVerified[] = $user['uid'];
    }
}
print_r($notVerified);
/*
  Array
  (
    [0] => 73943565
  ) 
*/
```

Отдельно стоит рассмотреть вариант, когда юзер заморожен (`deactivated => banned`) – верифицированные аккаунты, наверное, банят настолько редко, что можно считать все забаненные аккаунты неверифицированными, и тоже заносить их `uid` в результат. Но это уже вам решать.